# How can we connect to Amazon CloudWatch using boto3 with IAM role without using secret access key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

```
client = boto3.client('logs','us-west-2')
response = client.attach_role_policy(
    RoleName='',
    PolicyArn=''
)
```

The above code is giving me error:

> AttributeError: 'CloudWatchLogs' object has no attribute 'attach_role_policy'

Comment: Are you trying to run this in your local?

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana yes,i am running it on local

Answer (score -1):

The client you have defined is a CloudWatch Logs client, which has no method called `attach_role_policy` - this is a method on the IAM client, so for example:

```
logs_client = boto3.client('logs','us-west-2')
iam_client = boto3.client('iam', 'us-west-2')
```

and then you can use

```
iam_client.attach_role_policy(...)
```